# Django - executing queries in save method

Tags: python, mysql, django

The following code:

```
>>> from mainapp.models import ServerType
>>> server_type = ServerType()
>>> server_type.name = 'Origin'
>>> server_type.save()
>>> server_type.id
4L
```

generates mysql log:

```
SET NAMES utf8
set autocommit=0
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
INSERT INTO `ServerType` (`name`, `description`) VALUES ('Origin', '')
commit
```

How does django know the new id without extra select statement?

django=1.4

mysql=5.1

Comment: In addition to Daniels, answer, you can read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html - It is specific to mysql, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database adapter always responds with the new primary key on an insert statement. No extra queries required.